# 18.04 Ubuntu does not shutdown properly on laptop

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown, ssd

I have a Gigabyte p25x-v2 laptop which I have only upgraded SSD from 250 * 2 GB RAID to 1TB + 500GB.

Here are some more detailed specifications

- **CPU:** i7-4810MQ
- **GPU:** GTX 880M
- **RAM:** 8 * 2 GB
- **SSD 1:** Evo 860 mSATA 1TB
- **SSD 2:** Evo 860 mSATA 500GB
- **HDD:** 1TB

SSD 1 is used for Windows OS and SSD 2 is separately used for Ubuntu OS while HDD is used for data storage only.

Firmware for both SSDs and BIOS are up-to-date, secure boot option is off and I have tested on a complete mint condition of Ubuntu 18.04, but it still does not shut down and stays as shown below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Shutdown Sequence
[image: Screenshot]

I have seen many laptop users with Windows + Ubuntu dual booting system having similar issue as mine, but the difference is that:

1. I have two different OS installed on two separate SSD as I mentioned earlier
2. I have no re-boot issue, but shut down issue only.

This is really, really and really driving me crazy and I am eager to fix this issue...

It would have been easier if I got any sort of error message, but I am not getting any...

**EDIT:** Okay... I also tried installing grub bootloader into Ubuntu's SSD instead of Windows' one, but no luck :(

**EDIT 2:** Currently testing only with ubuntu SSD installed on this laptop.
(physically removed Windows installed SSD)

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  If you push the ESC key during shutdown, it should show you the shutdown sequence.  Can you please edit your question to include a picture of that?  Thanks!

Comment: @tudor Hi tudor! I saw that functionality(?) from other thread and tried holding ESC key for 5 seconds as well as pressing it once, but did not show up any shutdown sequence for me :/

Comment: Yeah, you only need to tap it once, and it needs to be early, as soon as you see the purple screen.  It's possible that the lockup is happening early.

Comment: @tudor I am not sure if I did get it properly, but I have edited the question to include the screenshot of shutdown sequence. Hope this helps!

Comment: So you're saying it gets to "reboot: Power down" but doesn't power down?

Comment: @tudor Exactly, sir! I left my laptop like that for couple of hours, then came back, but it was still on that screen :/

Comment: Ok.  Have you checked your BIOS is up to date?  The kernel does nothing after that point except send the restart signal.

Comment: @tudor AFAIK, the last BIOS update released by the manufacturer, Gigabyte, was out in 2015 for this specific model and yes, I did update the BIOS long time ago ;) https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/P25X-v2/support#support-dl-bios